# выборка по частичному совпадению значений из другой таблицы

Tags: sqlite

Есть две таблицы. Основная и содержащая слова-исключения.

Первая основная (образно tab1)

```
Id | Title
1  | Яблоко красное
2  | Зеленое яблоко
3  | Спелый апельсин
4  | Желтый банан
5  | Киви зеленое
```

Вторая таблица tab2

```
Id | ExceptWord
1  | яблоко
2  | киви
```

Смысл запроса - вывести все записи столбца Title таблицы №1, кроме тех что совпадают частично со всем содержимым стоблца ExceptWord таблицы №2

Работает следующий запрос:

```
SELECT Title FROM tab1 WHERE Title NOT IN (SELECT ExceptWord FROM tab2)
```

Но он выводит только по точному совпадению всей фразы. Не могу додумать, когда прикрутить LIKE%%, чтобы в конечном итоге вернулись две записи "Спелый апельсин" и "Желтый банан".

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t_1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
           FROM t_2
          WHERE t_1.title LIKE ('%' || t_2.exceptword || '%')
       )
;
```

Не забывайте, что для поддержки русских букв должно быть загружено
соотв. расширение и установлены прагмы.

Comment: То же как и ответ gil9red работает. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, примерно такой будет запрос `sqlite`:

```sql
SELECT Title FROM tab1
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM tab2 where lower(tab1.title) like '%' || lower(ExceptWord) || '%') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = []
letters2 = []
count = 0
for item in tab1[:]:
   for item2 in tab2[:]:
       for letter in str (item.title()):
           for letter2 in str (item2.title()):
                count += 1
                letters.append (letter)
                letters2.append (letter2)
                if count == len (str (item)):
                     count = 0
                     if not (letters == letters2):
                          print (item)
                          print (item2)
```

Попробуйте так. Не знаю,что получится!

Comment: Вопрос не по питону ведь? Кст, а зачем `str (item.title())`, `title()` же и так строку вернет? Вместо `if not (letters == letters2):` проще на `не` проверить: `if letters != letters2:`.

Comment: да... так себе у меня

Comment: Благодарю. Тоже мысль была циклом прогнать. И это будет работать нормально, если записей не много. А если несколько тысяч.. Вера в то, что можно все равно как-то выдернуть нужые данные одним запросом не покидает меня )

Comment: да... оцените мой ответ пж

Comment: Для поиска подстроки можно использовать оператор `in`, а для исключения вхождения `not in`. Для приведения к общему регистру используйте `lower` или `upper`. Например: `"яблоко" not in "Яблоко красное".lower()`. Если использовать эту логику можно два цикла убрать из кода. И не нужно делать копии `tab1` и `tab2`, вы ведь значения не меняете

Comment: да. Это верно. А у меня...