# Как пройтись по html таблице с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

У меня есть Html страница и на ней размещена таблица.

```js
var t = document.getElementById('table');
var tra = t.getElementsByTagName('tbody'); // Здесь выскакивает ошибка
var trs = tra.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var tds = null;
var sum;

for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
  tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var n = 0; n < trs.length; n++) {
    sum += "array[]=" + tds[n]
    if (i != trs.length - 1) {
      sum += "&"
    }
  }
}

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<div tag="table_div">
  <table border="1" id="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>...</tr>/и так далее
      <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Он не работает. В чём проблема? Или как мне правильно пройтись по всем элементам таблицы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [выборка по частичному совпадению значений из другой таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125396/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var t = document.getElementById('table');
var tra = t.children;
var trs = tra[0].children;
var tds = null;
var sum = 0;

for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++)  {
    tds = trs[i].children;
    for (var n=0; n<tds.length;n++)  {
        sum += parseInt(tds[n].innerText);
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<div tag="table_div">
    <table border="1" id="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>...</tr>/и так далее
        <tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Но у меня возникла новая проблема. Дело в том что я создаю таблицу с помощью php скрипта. И Js наотрез отказывается видеть <tbody>. Что с этим можно сделать? Пишет Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Comment: переменная из которой вы пытаетесь получить список дочерних элементов не присвоилось значения, смотрите выше ошибку в той строке где этой переменной присваиваете значение используйте console.log() где нужно посмотреть результат функции

Comment: В том то и дело, что я первым делом посмотрел что мне выводит console.log саму <table> которая динамически создается JS прекрасно находит а именно <tbody> найти не может.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sum = "";
document.querySelectorAll("#table tr").forEach(tr => {
  var cells = [];
  tr.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td => cells.push(td.textContent));
  sum += "row=" + cells.join("&");
});

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<div tag="table_div">
  <table border="1" id="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>...</tr>/и так далее
      <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```